# How to intercept link requests in a webView?

Tags: android, facebook, webview

I have a WebView which contains a Facebook button, it opens a link to the site with a post already done.
I want to know how to intercept the request and open it in the facebook application rather than on the browser. However, if Facebook apps is on the smartphone.

Thank you for your reply, and sorry for my English medium.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This can be achieved by setting the webviewclient eg.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.startsWith("http://blablablacatchurl")) {

            //we have intercepted the desired url call
            return true;
        }

        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
    }
});
```

If you want to see if there is a way to deep link to the facebook app, just package the url in an intent and fire it off and see what responds. If facebook doesn't catch it I don't think you can perform the second part of your request in any other way.

Comment: I tested this idea, it is good for the facebook link, but all of my other link opens in my webview and not in a browser as desired.

This problem can be treated by putting an "if" for every link, but do not have it a better idea?

Comment: add an else clause, pack the url into a new intent and fire it off and then return true so that the webview doesn't load the url as well.

Comment: I'm stupid for not having thought, I should not be awake, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());

    private class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            Uri uri;

            try {
                uri = Uri.parse(url);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // let Android deal with this
                return true;
            }

            String host = uri.getHost(); //Host is null when user clicked on email, phone number, ...

            if (host != null && host.equals("stackoverflow.com")) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
                return false;
            }
            else {
                // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs or anything else (email, phone number, ...)
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of not firing shouldOverrideUrlLoading method you could override `onPageStarted` or `shouldInterceptRequest` methods. They both have WebView as method parameter so you can redirect webview. but if you want to reach webview it must be final and it should run on different thread

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(final WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
    Log.i(TAG, "shouldInterceptRequest loading " + request.getMethod() + " " + request.getUrl().toString());
    String url = request.getUrl().toString();
    request.getRequestHeaders();
    if (url.contains("something important")){
        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (view.canGoBack())
                    view.goBack();
                else
                    Log.e(TAG, "can NOT go back");
            }
        });
    }

    return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebViewClient class and override url loading.

Comment: same problem as mentioned above :).