# Redirecting specific urls in Android webview to a native page

Tags: java, android, android-webview

I am currently testing a web app for the first time by using a webview. How could I intercept urls so that when a specific url is called, for example domain.com/login or domain.com/register it exits the webview and instead takes user to the native activity_login and activity_register page?

I tried googling and looking at past submissions here and could not find how to do this. If you could provide a code example that would really help. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function called [`shouldOverrideUrlLoading`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldOverrideUrlLoading(android.webkit.WebView,%20android.webkit.WebResourceRequest)) given API level >= 24 (Android 7.0).

Return `true` if you want to perform a custom action and `false` to let the page load normally.

For this example I am assuming you want to redirect requests to `domain.com/login` to a class/Activity called `LoginActivity` in your app. Add this code to the `onCreate` of the activity containing the `webView`:

```java
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebRequest request)
    {
        String url = request.getUrl().toString();

        if (url.contains("domain.com/login") {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity::class.java));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
});
```

Additional reading:

- [Bojan Kseneman on "How to intercept link requests in a webView?"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29719225/2111778)
- [Giru Bhai on "Difference between `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` and `shouldInterceptRequest`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29839731/2111778)